# detect if extended desktop is to the left or to the right

Tags: c++, windows, desktop, screenshot

So, I have a screen capture utility (it takes full screen shots and saves it to png files) I've written, and it uses `SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN` and `SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN` to determine the width and height of the desktop.

I then get the desktop DC and copy out the bits and save them as png.

```
    BitBlt(
      backDC, 0, 0,
      backBufferCX, backBufferCX,
      desktopDC, X_SRC, 0, SRCCOPY );
```

Here `X_SRC` is usually 0, UNLESS THE DESKTOP HAS BEEN EXTENDED "TO THE LEFT".  In that case it needs to be -1280px, for example, if the left monitor measures 1280px.

How can I determine if the desktop's starting point is negative (if the user has extended his desktop to the left?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the positioning information for all of the monitors via the [EnumDisplayMonitors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162610%28VS.85%29.aspx) method.

Or, if you only care about the corners of the virtual screen, you can pass `SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN` and `SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN` into the `GetSystemMetrics` method.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `GetSystemMetrics(SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN)` as the x, y coordinates to `BitBlt`